# for what values of $k$ $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}{xy\over(x^2+y^2)^{5\over 2}}[1-\cos (x^2+y^2)] & (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\ k & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

could anyone give me hints how to solve this one?

I tried to  find $\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ but did not proceed much. Thank you.

Comment: I edited to make the question more readable. Please make sure that I didn't introduce any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Approach $(0,0)$ along the $x$ and $y$ axis.

> If the limit exists then it should agree with limit we get by approaching along the $x$ and $y$ axis. Taking either $x=0$ or $y=0$ (but not both) we get that $f(x,y)=0$ arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$. This is independent of choosing $k$. Hence $k$ must be $0$ if $f$ were to be continuous. Now we show that if $k=0$ then $f$ is continuous. Writing this in polar co-ordinates gives $\frac{xy}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}(1-\cos(x^{2}+y^{2}))=\frac{r^{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r^{5}}(1-\cos(r^{2}))=\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\frac{1-\cos(r^{2})}{r^{3}}$. Apply L'hopitals rule to $\frac{1-\cos(r^{2})}{r^{3}}$ to show that this goes to $0$.

Comment: just tell me is it wrong? $${xy\over x^2+y^2}.\times {\sin^2(x^2+y^2)\over (x^2+y^2)^2}\times (x^2+y^2)^{1\over 2}=0\times 1\times 0=0$$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: this may not be much help but the only thing to do is to decide if the limit exists or not and, if it exists, to find its value. Because of the uniqueness of the limit, when it exists, you will have at most one possible value for $k$.

Edit: To calculate the limit multiply numerator and denominator by $ 1 + \cos (x^2 + y^2)$. If you isolate $\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ from the resulting expression it's easy to prove that this goes to $0$ and the other part goes to $1/2$ by standard manipulations.

Comment: are you telling this? just tell me is it wrong? $${xy\over x^2+y^2}.\times {\sin^2(x^2+y^2)\over (x^2+y^2)^2}\times (x^2+y^2)^{1\over 2}=0\times 1\times 0=0$$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?

Comment: It's wrong. Go through your calculations. Also, the first factor of the product you wrote does not tend to zero as can be seen approaching $(0,0)$ over the line $y=x$.

Comment: oh sorry first factor goes to $1\over 2$ via $y=x$

Comment: I'm afraid the first factor does not go to $\frac{1}{2}$. In fact the limit does not exist. Consider the line $y=\alpha x$. Along this line, for $x\neq0$, we get $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{\alpha x^{2}}{x^{2}+\alpha^{2}x^{2}}=\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha^{2}}$. What you can say is that $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is bounded in absolute value. If $x=0$ or $y=0$ then $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is $0$. Otherwise, since $0\le(|x|-|y|)^{2}=x^{2}-2|x||y|+y^{2}$ so $|xy|\le\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2}$. Thus $|\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}|\le\frac{1}{2}$. So $|\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}|\le\frac{1}{2}$ in both cases.

Comment: Also $1-\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})\neq\sin^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})$. I think you are thinking of $\sin^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})+\cos^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})=1$. However, $1-\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})=\frac{1-\cos^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}{1+cos(x^{2}+y^{2})}=\frac{\sin^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}{1+\cos(x^{2}+y^{2})}$